# Remove duplicate element in a list of list in Python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I have a list like this :

```
[{'score': '92', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Door'},
 {'score': '61', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Sliding Door'}]
```

I want to remove the duplicate images based on their imageId. So in the above example the imageID 6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0 is present 2 times (keep the one with the highest score).

How to do that in Python ?

Comment: How do you decide which entry to remove? Look at the score? There are two ways to solve this, either a "clean-up" function, or creating a custom class which automatically rejects entering two images with the same ID, or alternatively automatically chooses the one with the highest score upon adding it to the list.

Comment: Provide more clarification

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa It's best to keep the one with the highest score.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to keep the entry with the highest score here. Try this:

```
my_list = [
    {'score': '92', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Door'},
    {'score': '61', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Sliding Door'}
]

by_id = {}
for element in my_list:
   imageId = element['imageId']
   if imageId in by_id:
       if int(by_id[imageId]['score']) < int(element['score']):
           # Replace because of higher score
           by_id[imageId] = element
   else:
       # Insert new element
       by_id[imageId] = element

print(list(by_id.values()))
```

Comment: try with `score = "100"`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre well spotted

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby`,

```
from itertools import groupby
new_list = [max(list(l),key=lambda x:x['score']) for _,l in groupby(sorted(lst,key=lambda x:x['imageId']),lambda x:x['imageId'])]
```

Execution:

```
In [41]: lst = [{'score': '92', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Door'}, {'score': '61', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Sliding Door'}]

In [42]: print [max(list(l),key=lambda x:x['score']) for g,l in groupby(lst,lambda x:x['imageId'])]    
[{'score': '92', 'label': 'Door', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0'}]
```

Comment: it doesn't work with a more complex example where dupes aren't consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you enhance your example slightly so:

- it tests numeric comparisons
- it has non-consecutive "duplicate" elements

I would create a marker dict with id as key and sublist as value. Loop on the input and overwrite dict entry if the value is higher (don't forget to cast to integer)

```
my_list = [
    {'score': '192', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Door'},
    {'score': '61', 'imageId': 'fffffe26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'misc'},
    {'score': '761', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Sliding Door'},
    {'score': '45', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Door'},
]

import collections

d = dict()

for subdict in my_list:
    score = int(subdict['score'])
    image_id = subdict['imageId']
    if image_id not in d or int(d[image_id]['score']) < score:
        d[image_id] = subdict

new_list = list(d.values())
```

result (order may change as we used a dictionary):

```
[{'imageId': 'fffffe26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0',
  'label': 'misc',
  'score': '61'},
 {'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0',
  'label': 'Sliding Door',
  'score': '761'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a massiv load of data, just do it with pandas.DataFrame, its cleaner to read and to maintain.

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [
    {'score': '192', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Door'},
    {'score': '61', 'imageId': 'fffffe26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'misc'},
    {'score': '761', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Sliding Door'},
    {'score': '45', 'imageId': '6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0', 'label': 'Door'},
]

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)

# your score is string! convert it to int
df['score'] = df['score'].astype('int')

# sort values
df = df.sort_values(by=['imageId', 'score'], ascending=False)

# drop duplicates
df = df.drop_duplicates('imageId', keep='first')


    imageId                                 label           score
1   fffffe26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0    misc            61
2   6184de26-e11d-4a7e-9c44-a1af8012d8d0    Sliding Door    761
```